# is it possible to check the conditions and update jsonb

Tags: postgresql

```
    {
  "type_A": {
    "Food": [
      {
        "Pizza": 1
      },
      {
        "Pasta": 4
      },
      {
        "Rosted nuts": 2
      }
    ],
    "drinks": [
      {
        "coka cola": 8
      },
      {
        "moka": 1
      },
      {
        "wine": 16
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Suppose I have above JSON present in the database when I get a web request and it contains pizza then I want to check the first, pizza is available in type food or not, if not present then add it and if present then update the quantity as give in web req.

Is it possible using a query?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? That you don't where (or how often) a `pizza` object occurs in the array? I'd suggest to not use an array of single-property objects at all.

Comment: actually here I mention only 3 menu items but at run time it might be more than 100 and types can be food, soft drinks, and many more category.

Comment: type_A belongs to the time window like morning 9-12

Comment: How does the data from the web request look like?

Comment: later on, food can also categorize into fast food, junk food, breakfirst

Comment: basically, when customer order something then it will appear in the request so I can collect all the menu along with its type of categories like food or drink after that I will add it in JSON field as per request.

Comment: i.e we have 1000 menu items but not all item were ordered by the customer so I decided to get the menu appears in web req and only those will push inside an array  of JSON, if menu item present then add qty only other add name and quantity

Comment: idea is to find out the food serve on the table. (analytics)

Comment: Please show a concrete example of the request data for updating pizza, you can [edit] your question

Comment: I will update it soon, thank you for showing your interest in the issue and help.